# sharing variables between classes in Swift

Tags: swift

I am just getting into Swift and struggling how to simply set a text property of a label in one class based on a variable in another. In one swift file I have:

```
Class GameController:

var instructsText = String()

func gameControl()
instructsText = array[2] as string //this gets the instructions text from a Plist file.
```

In another swift file I have

```
Class HelpViews: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {

// add the instructions label
var instructsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/2-300, ScreenHeight-150, 600, 100))
instructsLabel.text = instructsText - ERROR 'instructs is not a subtype of 'NSString'
self.addSubview(instructsLabel)
```

any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Post real code please.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you would be getting the error you say you are. At no point, (at least in the code above) do you make an object of the GameController Class and thus the compiler should be telling you that it does not recognize the variable `instructsText`. However, I would suggest using a computed class property. An example of one would be:

```
class MyClass {
class var pi: Double { return 3.1415926 }
// ...
}
println(MyClass.pi)
```

Which would print out 3.1415926. In you code, one way that might work is as follows:

```
Class GameController:

class var instructsText = String {return array[2] as String}
```

And in the HelpView Class:

```
Class HelpViews: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {

// add the instructions label
var instructsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/2-300, ScreenHeight-150, 600, 100))
instructsLabel.text = GameController.instructsText
self.addSubview(instructsLabel)
```

The Apple Swift documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried class var in GameController but it says "Class variables not supported".

Comment: If you just type in `class var pi = 3.14` then you will get the error "Class variables are not yet supported." You need to use the syntax above, with the brackets and `return` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to println(instructsText) variable, to see what you try to set.
Here is a few cases:

1. Not declared variable
2. It could be nil
3. It's not String